# Sharing a library between multiple userscripts

Tags: javascript, require, userscripts

I have a library script that's used by multiple userscripts. This library does some heavy lifting (i.e. CPU-intensive operations), so I would like to have only 1 instance of that library running.

Here's a minimal example:

**lib.js**

```
let callbacks = [];

document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // pretend that something expensive happens in here

    for (callback of callbacks)
        callback();
});
```

**script1.user.js**

```
// @match foo.bar
// @require lib.js

callbacks.push(function(){
    console.log('Script 1: '+callbacks.length+' callback(s) registered');
});
```

**script2.user.js**

```
// @match foo.bar
// @require lib.js

callbacks.push(function(){
    console.log('Script 2: '+callbacks.length+' callback(s) registered');
});
```

With this setup, the output after a mouse click would be:

```
Script 1: 1 callback(s) registered
Script 2: 1 callback(s) registered
```

because each userscript has its own instance of the library. What can I do to make them use the same library instance, so I get an output like this:

```
Script 1: 2 callback(s) registered
Script 2: 2 callback(s) registered
```

Note:

- Both userscripts run on the same page
- The userscripts may or may not have `@grant none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be for the library script to assign itself to the window *if it does not exist there yet*, standard singleton style.

**lib.js**

```
const win = typeof unsafeWindow === 'undefined' ? window : unsafeWindow;

if (!win.myLib) {
  win.myLib = {
    callbacks: []
    // assign other properties/methods as needed
  };

  document.addEventListener('click', function(){
    for (const callback of win.myLib.callbacks)
      callback();
  });
}
```

**script1.user.js**

```
// @require lib.js
const { myLib } = window;
myLibrary.callbacks.push(function(){
  console.log('Script 1: ' + myLib.callbacks.length + ' callback(s) registered');
});
```

**script2.user.js**

```
// @require lib.js
const { myLib } = window;
myLibrary.callbacks.push(function(){
  console.log('Script 2: ' + myLib.callbacks.length + ' callback(s) registered');
});
```

Depending on the userscript manager, you may have to use `unsafeWindow` instead in some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. I've experimented a little, and it seems that I have to use `unsafeWindow` in scripts that don't have `@grant none`. It's a bit annoying that I have to refer to the library's functions as `myLibrary.someFunction`, but I can live with that.

Comment: If you wanted it would be easy to extract all the library functions at the top level of the userscript before doing anything else, eg `const { callbacks, libraryFn1, libraryFn2, libraryFn3 } = window.myLibrary;`